# Where to define properties that are common for all Solr cores?

Tags: solr

I use Solr 5.3.

I have few cores. At the moment, custom properties for each core are defined in `my_core_x/core.properties` file. However, all custom properties are the same for all cores. So, I have multiple identical `core.properties` files.

Is it possible to define properties somewhere else, in one place only?

EDIT: I want to use these custom properties in `solrconfig.xml` like this:

```
${my.custom.property}
```

Comment: No, There is no way to define a global `core.properties` file in solr.

The `core.properties` files are used to define a core in solr. When you launch the solr service, it automatically detects all the `core.properties` under solr.home directory.

Comment: I want to define some CUSTOM properties somewhere. I put them into core.properties for now. I want tu use them in solconfig.xml later, like this: ${my.custom.property}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom properties through the regular `-D` syntax when starting Solr / the JVM.

From [Configuring solrconfig.xml](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Configuring+solrconfig.xml):

> Any JVM System properties, usually specified using the -D flag when starting the JVM, can be used as variables in any XML configuration file in Solr.
>
> For example, in the sample solrconfig.xml files, you will see this value which defines the locking type to use:
>   <lockType>${solr.lock.type:native}</lockType>
>
> Which means the lock type defaults to "native" but when starting Solr, you could override this using a JVM system property by launching the Solr it with:
>
> `bin/solr start -Dsolr.lock.type=none`

Comment: This answer lead me to to the right path. I set custom properties to SOLR_OPTS environment variable defined in the Solr include file (bin/solr.in.sh)